# FOR loop over a date range in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In one of my functions in Postgres, I am trying to loop over a range of dates using the following code:

```
FOR timesheet_date IN select generate_series('2012-11-24'::date,'2012-12-03','1 day'::interval)::date LOOP

//My code goes here

END LOOP;
```

But I am getting an error [image]

Now as am getting dates, I think it is not a record variable and hence the error.

But, how can I loop through a date range ? I am very new to Postgres actually.

Comment: So how is the variable `timesheet_date` defined?

Comment: It is defined as a date

Comment: You need to show the complete function. The error is occurring as you did not `DECLARE` `timesheet_date` correctly. As the error states it needs to be a `record` or a list. See [Looping through query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

Comment: Maybe you even don't need a loop.

Comment: Generally, one does not use loops in SQL. Depends on what you're doing in the loop. Consider joining with `generate_series` instead.

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=333420204f0fd4194a6e3454e3876e01)  (the insert into the output table is only done because DBFiddle doesn't show results of `raise notice`)

Comment: Please show a complete function including the header. The mini snippet you show is not enough. The error msg as plain text. And always your version of Postgres. The error msg indicates you messed up the declaration of `timesheet_date`.

Answer (score 3):

```
DO $$
declare
    dt record;
begin
FOR dt IN SELECT generate_series('2023-02-10'::date, '2023-02-15'::date, '1 day'::interval) LOOP
  RAISE NOTICE 'Processing date: %', dt.generate_series;
END LOOP;
end; $$
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.